# Inquiries about checking messages, message body bytes, and process memory of a specific queue in rabbitMQ's management console

Tags: rabbitmq, rmq

You can check messages, message body bytes, and process memory for a specific queue in rabbitMQ's management console. You can check the ever-changing Total, Ready, Unacked, In memory, Persistent, Transient, and Paged Out values. What I'm curious about is, can I check the max value for this? Or can I set a specific period to view it?

I checked the Messages, Message body bytes, and Process memory values ​​of a specific queue in rabbitMQ's management console, and expected to see the max value and whether it could be checked at a specific time.